# Nesting sections in Blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I'm looking at how Blade implements the @section, but it works a little different than I'm used to with Twig. It seems that you can't nest @sections in each other.

Example:

**_layout.blade.php** (basic layout file)

```
<html>

    //favicons
    //meta content
    //other basic shizzle

    <head>
        <title>overal</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        @yield('body_content')
    </body>

</html>
```

**website.blade.php** (specific implementation)

```
@extend('_layout.blade.php')

@section('body_content')

    <div class="">
        website-header
    </div>

    <div class="main">

        @section('navigation')
            <nav>website navigation</nav>
        @endsection

        <div class="website">

            {-- the actual content --}
            @yield('content')

        </div>

    </div>

@endsection
```

**blog.blade.php** (implementation for the blog-page)

```
@extend('website.blade.php')

@section('content')
    blog-items
@endsection
```

**faq.blade.php** (implementation for the faq-page)

```
@extend('website.blade.php')

{{-- we don't want the navigation here or want something different --}}
@section('nav')@endsection

@section('content')
    faq-items
@endsection
```

And I can't solve it with @includes, since I want the flexibility to be able to determine sub-sub sections in sub-views and overwrite their content.

Comment: You can pass variables from views to views by using `@extend('website.blade.php', ['nav' => false])`, you could then query this variable in your `website.blade.php` and remove the nav (for this specific instance, this might give you some place to extend from)

Comment: Well, I don't want to cluther my base templates (or how deep it might go) with variables in case a child needs an overwrite / something else.

But it is possible... so my question is not relevant anymore. I did post this below, in case someone might look for the same :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind, this **is** possible
It was my editor (PhpStorm) that was bugging me. You **CAN** nest @section in each other and overwrite/redefine them in extended templates ^^

W00000t

Comment: I have reported this as a bug in PhpStorm - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-43311